# JavaScript calculation including decimal places

Tags: javascript

First of all, apologies im not very good with Java Script. What im trying to achieve is the following calculation to include decimal places

```
<script>
    function calc() {
        var cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;
        var singleShare = document.getElementById('singleShare').value;
        var priceShare = document.getElementById('priceShare').value;

        var cost1 = parseInt(cost) || 0;
        var singleShare1 = parseInt(singleShare) || 0;
        var priceShare1 = parseInt(priceShare) || 0;

        var pv = (parseInt(priceShare1, 10) * 10000) / (parseInt(cost1, 10) * parseInt(singleShare1, 10));

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ('P/V = '+pv.toFixed(2)+'%');
    }
</script>
```

The input comes from the following form inputs:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="singleShare">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="priceShare" onkeyup="calc();">
```

The function works great for round numbers, but as soon as I put a decimal place in like the following calculation

cost 120
singleShare 2.5
priceShare 3.25

The result should be 108.33%

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s because you’re using `parseInt`, which parses an integer. Try using `parseFloat` instead. Note that `parseFloat` doesn’t take a radix—you’ll need to omit the `10` argument wherever it’s currently included if you wish to use `parseFloat`.